# How to convert pandas dataframe to snowpark dataframe?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowpark

How to convert pandas dataframe back to snowpark dataframe?

```
pandas_df = snowpark_df.to_pandas()
...
???
```

Comment: Can you give us more context?

Comment: A snowpark dataframe is a table in Snowflake.  So, use `write_pandas()` to write the data in the dataframe back to a Snowflake table, and then you can set that table to be a snowpark dataframe.

Comment: Basically getting snowflake table into Snowpark, dataframe, converting it to pandas to take advantage of the functionality, and once transformed, save it back to snowflake.

Comment: Mike, the write_pandas only works with snowflake connector, and not snowpack library, right?

Comment: Snowpark supports `write_pandas`. Proof: https://github.com/snowflakedb/snowpark-python/blob/75beddbedfb49eeca1ac25f88e420bf1c8fb145d/src/snowflake/snowpark/session.py#L970

Answer (score 10):

Try this:

```
session.create_dataframe(pandas_df)
```

or alternatively this:

```
session.write_pandas(pandas_df, ...)
```

You can read about it in the docs [here](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/snowpark/reference/python/latest/api/snowflake.snowpark.Session.createDataFrame) and [here](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/snowpark/reference/python/latest/api/snowflake.snowpark.Session.write_pandas).

Comment: Could not edit the answer to update the link. [Docs](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/snowpark/reference/python/latest/api/snowflake.snowpark.Session.createDataFrame) regarding `createDataFrame`. And [docs](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/python-connector/python-connector-api#write_pandas) regarding `write_pandas`.

Comment: Thanks, I've just updated the links in the answer